# How many reputation points do you need before you can delete your own question or answer?

Tags: support, reputation, self-delete

As per the comments of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148658/java-list-use-through-use-of-jstl-cforeach/2148672#2148672):

> *Maybe it's due to your low reputation that you're unable to delete your own answer.*
>
> *It is because of my low rep. but i think the fact i can't delete my own answers is a bit lame.*

I checked the [help center about reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation), but I can't seem to find the minimum reputation one would need before being able to delete *own* question/answer.

Is there actually a minimum reputation for this? If so, how much is it? And can it be added to the SO FAQ as well to avoid future questions/confusions?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stack-overflow

Comment: If you search for info in the FAQ, don't miss this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless something changed *very* recently, you don't need any rep to delete your own answers, **provided you're using a registered (OpenID) account**.

(Same goes for questions, although there are additional restrictions if answers have been posted and up-voted.)

Note that "[Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259453/mark)" (the user in the question you link to) is *not* a registered user, and therefore cannot delete his posts unless/until he associates an OpenID with his account.

#### See: [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)

Comment: Thank you, he was indeed unregistered.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more *unabridged* version of that FAQ:

[How does “Reputation” work on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stack-overflow)

- You need "+250 to vote to open/close your own questions."

And according to this:

[What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-can-a-question-or-answer-be-deleted)...

- "You can delete your own post, provided you have registered  your account (logged in using an OpenID)"
- "You can't delete your answer if it has been accepted."
- "You can't delete your question if the total score of all answer(s) to it is >= 2, or it has been closed  less than 48 hours ago."
- "Deleted answers can be viewed, edited, and undeleted by their original authors, however deleted questions cannot be seen by their authors (unless they have a reputation >= 10K or happen to be moderators)."